# Eclipse Android Compat Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Can someone help me please ? I've been working on it for 6 hours. I've watched many videos and looked forums. I've tried to use Eclipse with Genymotion. I built the SDK but I couldn't solve app compat problem 
Here is the problem
E:\AndroidProjects\sdsfds\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

I tried to import Compat file but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should use android studio for android development.

Comment: Official support for Eclipse ended nearly a year ago. There has not been an `appcompat-v7` published for use with the Eclipse+ADT combination in quite some time. If you are new to programming, either do not use Eclipse or do not use `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: Oh my god. So I wasted my time for nothing :'/. Thank you so much ...